# Loop an array value inside json object and convert it to single string

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, javascript-objects

so I have a JSON object here:

```
// TableData
{
    "0": {
        "damage_type": "Scratch",
        "regions": [
            "front side",
            "back side"
        ],
        "price": 100
    },
    "1": {
        "damage_type": "Scratch",
        "regions": [
            "front side",
            "back side,
            "right side"
        ],
        "price": 100
    }
}
```

And I want to convert it to something like this:

```
[
    {
        "damage_type": "Scratch",
        "regions": "front side;\nback side", // Notice the array become a single string and separated with ; and \n
        "price": 100
    },
    {
        "damage_type": "Scratch",
        "regions": "front side;\nback side;\nright side", 
        "price": 100
    }
]
```

*Notice the array become a single string and separated with ; and \n*

Does anybody have any idea how to reach that result?

**My current (and unsuccessful) approach:**

I am looping it like this:

```
  import data from '../data/table.json'


  const stringData = JSON.stringify(data)
  const tableData = JSON.parse(stringData)
  let processedData: any[] = []
  for(var i = 0; i <= Object.keys(data).length - 1 ; i++){
    processedData.push(tableData[i])
  }


console.log(processedData)
```

And the result is still like this:

```
[
    {
                "damage_type": "Scratch",
                "regions": ["Front Side", "Back side"],
                "price": 100
    },
    {
                "damage_type": "Scratch",
                "regions": ["Front Side", "Back side", "Right side"], // This part is still an array
                "price": 100
    }
]
```

To make everything easier please go https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3xb5y4qn8

Comment: have you tried this -  `processedData.push(tableData[i].join(";/"))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use following approach:

```
Object.values(TableData).map((item) => {
 return {...item, regions: item.regions.join(';\n')};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const TableData = {
    "0": {
        "damage_type": "Scratch",
        "regions": [
            "front side",
            "back side"
        ],
        "price": 100
    },
    "1": {
        "damage_type": "Scratch",
        "regions": [
            "front side",
            "back side",
            "right side"
        ],
        "price": 100
    }
}

const processedData = Object.values(TableData).map(row => ({
  ...row,
  regions: row.regions.join(';\n'),
}));

console.log(processedData)
```